Execute an encrypted script Bash
Please, how can I execute a script (bash) after encrypting it without decrypting it?
I would like to give only execute access to a script and make it unreadable.
I used this to encrypt my script openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in test.sh -out test.sh.enc -k $Password

You can't execute a script without decrypting it. You can decrypt it to standard input of a shell, but then your user can use something else than a shell to save the decrypted code.

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in test.sh.enc -k "$Password" | bash

How would the script even know that it's executed by a "real" bash and not some other program pretending to be bash?

What are you trying to do? Most people would use a compiled language to hide the source code, maybe with an obfuscator. But I've never seen someone go through that effort for a shell script.

Write your secret bash script:
secret.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf 'Hello the world from my secret encrypted bash script!\n'

Encrypt your secret.sh:
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in secret.sh -out secret.sh.enc -k "$Password"

Write a loader that will be able to decode and execute its embedded encrypted bash script separated by a null character:
secret-loader.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -rsp 'Enter password: ' password
echo
{
    IFS= read -rd '' # Read through launcher until null character and leave binary blob
    if ! openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k "$password" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Invalid password!\n' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
} < "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
{
    IFS= read -rd ''
    openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k "$password" 2> /dev/null | bash
} < "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
exit

Combine the loader and the encrypted payload:
{ cat secret-loader.sh; printf '\0'; cat secret.sh.enc;} > encrypted
chmod +x encrypted

Now run your new encrypted bash script:
./encrypted

